# seasoning meat overnight with crème fraîche?

Tags: seasoning

What does the crème fraîche do?
thanks

The day before you want to serve this dish, season the beef shoulder with salt and ground black pepper, and put the beef in a nonreactive container, such as Pyrex. Pour the 1 cup crème fraîche over it. Roll the beef shoulder to make sure it is completely covered with crème fraîche. Cover and refrigerate overnight.